# selenium getting only first page results in loop

Tags: python, selenium

I'm having difficulty figuring out why my code will not refresh the DOM and grab new results.  I want to grab on each page:

case title
date
pdf links
details links

The script grabs the 1st page results and clicks on the "next button" and the table counter continues increasing, however the following results are from the first page after each next button click.

The web page is [here](https://www.govinfo.gov/app/collection/uscourts/district/caed/2021/%7B%22pageSize%22%3A%22500%22%2C%22offset%22%3A%220%22%7D)

My relevant code:

```
    url = https://www.govinfo.gov/app/collection/uscourts/district/caed/2021/%7B%22pageSize%22%3A%22500%22%2C%22offset%22%3A%220%22%7D
    driver.get(url)
    

    page = driver.page_source
    soup = bs(page, "html.parser")

    cnt = 0
    while True:
        tables = soup.find_all('table', class_='table')
        
            # WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//span[@class="custom-paginator"]')))
        for my_table in tables:

            cnt += 1
            print ('=============== Table {} ==============='.format(cnt))

            print('Court: ' + 'United States Court ' + value)
            rows = my_table.find_all('td')                  
            for row in rows:
                cells = row.find_all('b')
                """ getting case title"""         
                for cell in cells:
                    span_1 = cell.find('span', {'class':'results-line1'}).text
                    print('Case: ' + span_1)
                """getting case date"""
                next_cells = row.find_all('em')
                for next_cell in next_cells:
                    span_2 = next_cell.find('span', {'class':'results-line2'}).text
                    print('Date: ' + span_2)
                # links = []
                links = row.find_all('a', href=True)

                """grabbing the pdf link then the details link only"""
                for link in links:
                    
                    start_link = 'https://www.govinfo.gov'
                    pdf = (link.get('href'))
                    pdf_link = re.search("pdf$", pdf)
                    fixed_link = "".join((start_link,pdf))
                    if pdf_link:
                        print('Link: ' + fixed_link)
                    elif '/details' in pdf:
                        print('Details: ' + fixed_link)
                    else:
                        break
                    
                    

        try:
            next_page = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('fw-pagination-btn')
            if len(next_page) <1:
                print("No more pages left")
                break
            else:
                
                pages = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='custom-paginator']//li[@class='next fw-pagination-btn']/a")))
                page_count = 0
                print('clicking next button')
                page_count +=1
                print('---------page{}---------'.format(page_count))
                pages.click()
                
                time.sleep(7)
        except TimeoutException:
            break
    


driver.quit()
```

I can't seem to figure out how to refresh the data in the "try" section of the code.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you paste the code that defines what are `courts` and `court_names`?

Comment: Can you reproduce it with smaller and more specific code? Please give it a go in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I removed the reference to courts etc and just supplied one url as en example.  The try clause clicks the next button but the following results are from the 1st "page" on each next button click.